# Loading additional cells at the bottom of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am trying to automatically get and load the next page of cells when the user scrolls to the bottom of the`UICollectionView`.

I am able to do so by adding a `UIButton` in `UICollectoinView` footer. When user scrolls to the footer and touches the button, new cells are added correctly. `UIButton` in the footer can be touched again for adding more pages.

I tried to automate it so when the user scrolls to the bottom, the proper method for adding new cells is called automatically:

```
- (UICollectionReuseableView *)collectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind: (NSString *)kind atIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{

    // code for headerView
    // ...

    // code for footerView
    MySupplementalFooter *footerView = nil;
    if ( [kind isEqual:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter] )
    {
        footerView = [self.collectionView dequeueReuseableSupplemntaryViewOfKind:kind withReuseIdentifier:@"FooterId" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (LoadMoreIsEnabled) 
        {
            footerView.loadMoreFooterButton.setHidden:NO];
            [self loadMoreFooterButtonAction]; // calls the method to add cells to the dictionary for cv 
        } else 
        {
             footerView.loadMoreFooterButton setHidden:YES];
        }

        return footerView;
    }
}
```

The `loadMoreFooterButtonAction` method is called, but the entire `UICollectionView` blanks out. Refreshing the `UICollectionView` does not bring it back.

Comment: `UICollectionView blanks out` OMG, that was my case, I tried usual ways with `willDisplayCell` but collection view resets and becomes blank (wtf). Finally implemented using `scrollViewDidScroll`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're trying to do something like "infinite scrolling" from desktop webpages, where you load more content when a user gets to the bottom of a page. On iOS, this isn't a very commonly used design. Typically, developers will initialize their UITableView or UICollectionView with the absolute total number of entries. If they need to stream data over the network, they asynchronously load the data as needed (when cells or views come on screen) and until the content loads they show some kind of temporary content, like a blank view with a spinner.

That said, if you want to do infinite scrolling in a manner more like a desktop web app, you should implement the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol (or UICollectionViewDelegate, which is a superset) and listen for the [scrollViewDidScroll:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll%3a) callback. Within that callback, iterate through the UICollectionView's [indexPathsForVisibleItems](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/indexPathsForVisibleItems) and check to see if any of the index paths map to the 'last' item in your collection, which indicates the user has scrolled to the end. At that point, call your logic to load more stuff.

Comment: "Typically, developers will initialize their UITableView or UICollectionView with the absolute total number of entries." [citation needed]

Answer (score 20):

In IOS8 there is a `UICollectionViewDelegate` method `willDisplayCell`.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.item == (data.count-1) {
        loadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to add some behavior knowledge to this. If the user is scrolling up and down, even though at the end of this section, you might have a situation where loadData() is called more than once.  I have added a bool to control when loadData() can get called again.  However,  indexPath.item is exactly the dynamic reference to be used. Good call http://stackoverflow.com/users/2604669/nick-wargnier

Comment: `UICollectionView blanks out` does anyone experience this? I tried usual `willDisplayCell` but collection view resets and becomes blank (wtf).

Comment: @SoftDesigner I've had the same problem, and it turned out to be because reloadData wasn't being called on the main thread. I'm sure it's too late not, but for others in the future!

Comment: @SoftDesigner , I am facing the same problem. Did You find a solution?

Answer (score 15):

In table view, you should load more data in willDisplayCell() method. With collections, there is no such a counterpart. But, you can do like this. Hope, it helps.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Other code here ...

    if (indexPath.item == [self.photos count] - 1) {
        [self loadPhotos];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)loadPhotos {
    [self showLoadingIndicator];
    self.operation = [client HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [self hideLoadingIndicator];

        // Get data
        NSArray *photosData = responseObject[@"data"];
        NSInteger numberOfResults = [photosData count];
        NSInteger totalCount = [self.photos count];

        if (numberOfResults > 0) {
            NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];

            for (NSInteger i = 0; i < numberOfResults; i++) {
                Photo *photo = [Photo new];
                photo._id = [photoData[@"id"] integerValue];
                photo.url = photoData[@"url"];

                [self.photos addObject:photo];
                [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:totalCount + i
                                                     inSection:0]];
            }

            [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
                [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
            } completion:nil];
        }        
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [self hideLoadingIndicator];
        // Handle error here
    }];

   [self.operation start];
}
```

Comment: Now UICollectionView has willDisplayCell delegate in iOS8.

Comment: What  should we implement in loadMoredata method?

Comment: @Bhumica I updated my answer. This is an example with AFNetworking.

Comment: @vampirewalk But, a lot of apps still support iOS 7.

Comment: I am doing same. But, the problem is If I insert cells previous cells disappear then loaded and collectionView scrolls itself to top. @Sukhrob I am using Xcode for iOS app targeting iOS 10 and later.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but I'll provide a solution for future answer-seekers. Usually when I do infinite scrolling on a UITableView, I will check if the bounds of the tableView's scrollview intersect with the rect of the tableFooterView. Footer views are a little more complicated to get at in UICollectionViews, so I create a rect at the end of the collectionView, see if it intersects with the scrollView bounds, and if it does, I load more items. I've also checked that we have at least something in the table so I'm not going wild trying to load more right when the table instantiates.

Note: Your `more` method in this case will update your collectionView datasource, appending the new items. Your numberOfItems/sections methods should reflect the new counts.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(scrollView.bounds, CGRectMake(0, self.collectionView.contentSize.height, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 40)) && self.collectionView.contentSize.height > 0)
    {
        [self more];
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great for me in my collection view

Comment: This calls [self more] a bunch of times instead of just calling it once as expected.

Comment: Correct.  In more you will need to have add state to indicate if you are in the process of loading more.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `collectionView(_:prefetchItemsAt:)`
Tutorial [1](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/uicollectionview-prefetching-in-ios-10) and [2](https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/241-uicollectionview-cell-pre-fetching).

Answer (score -1):

I faced difficulty converting @sukhrob's answer to swift for my project so here is his code in Swift 3 for easy copy and paste.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // Other code here ...
        if indexPath.item == photos.count() - 1 {
            loadPhotos()
        }
        return cell
    }

    func loadPhotos() {
        showLoadingIndicator()
        operation = client.httpRequestOperation(with: request, success: {(_ operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation, _ responseObject: Any) -> Void in
            self.hideLoadingIndicator()
                // Get data
            let photosData: [Any] = responseObject["data"]
            let numberOfResults: Int = photosData.count
            let totalCount: Int = photos.count()
            if numberOfResults > 0 {
                var indexPaths = [Any]()
                var i = 0
                while i < numberOfResults {
                    let photo = Photo()
                    photo.id = CInt(photoData["id"])
                    photo.url = photoData["url"]
                    photos.append(photo)
                    indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: totalCount + i, section: 0))
                    i
                }
                i += 1

        collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({() -> Void in
                    collectionView?.insertItems(at: indexPaths as? [IndexPath] ?? [IndexPath]())
                }) { _ in }
            }
        }, failure: {(_ operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation, _ error: Error?) -> Void in
            self.hideLoadingIndicator()
            // Handle error here
        })
        operation.start()
```